# BaseRepository for EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is this okay?

```
public class BaseRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly DbContext _dbContext;

    public BaseRepository(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public T Get(Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        return GetAll(predicate).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll(Func<T, bool> predicate = null)
    {
        IEnumerable<T> result = _dbContext.Set<T>().AsEnumerable();
        return (predicate == null) ? result : result.Where<T>(predicate);
    }

    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        _dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;
    }

    public void Delete(Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        IEnumerable<T> entities = GetAll(predicate);
        foreach (T entity in entities)
            _dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted;
    }

    public void Delete(T entity)
    {
        _dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted;
    }

    public void Update(T entity)
    {
        _dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public async void Save()
    {
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_dbContext != null)
            _dbContext.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have used this layer/pattern for two years in my projects ... most because of all tutorials I have seen when I started on asp.NET MVC. IMHO, `abstract repository` exists just to abstract an existing abstraction. I am coding much happier now that I removed it from my code :)

Comment: My code review. This is going to bring down your entire application. Fix `Func<T, bool>` for `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`. Stop using `IEnumerable` if you don't know what it is vs `IQueryable`. Just use `var`.

Answer (score 5):

It seems strange to me for `Get` to be a specific way of getting all items, and `GetAll` should always return *all* items. Introduce a `GetSome` helper for clarity.

```
public T Get(Func<T, bool> predicate) {
    return GetWhere(predicate).FirstOrDefault();
}

public IEnumerable<T> GetAll() {
    return GetWhere(null);
}

public IEnumerable<T> GetWhere(Func<T, bool> predicate) {
    IEnumerable<T> result = _dbContext.Set<T>().AsEnumerable();
    return (predicate == null) ? result : result.Where<T>(predicate);
}
```

> Caveat: I don't write C# so perhaps this doesn't match the standard pattern there.

Comment: +1 thanks for the tip in my answer! I would use the names or Find and GetAll

Comment: Yes, in my Java DAOs I prefer `findBy...` and reserve `get...` for single-item finding methods that fail if no item is found.

Comment: I would probably consider passing in () => true rather than null for the GetSome() method.  Also maybe GetWhere instead of GetSome??

Comment: @dreza Great name! Regarding `null` versus a no-op predicate, can `Where` detect this and return the original result without scanning it needlessly?

Comment: hmmm, a good question!  My gut is it will still enumerate, but honestly I don't know.  The compiler might be clever enough to optimize it out.

Answer (score 4):

```
public async void Save()
    {
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

The name shall be SaveAsync code convention!

I would make the BaseRepository as abstract --> this will prevent the repository user from creating the Base Repository!

Comment: @DavidHarkness Yes I know it would be better if it do that!?

Answer (score 3):

Your `Get()` function firstly, should be named something appropriate, such as `First()` or `GetSingle()` (etc). Secondly, I would use `Expressions`, instead of `Func<>`, for the simple reason that an `IEnumerable<T>` will return the full contents of a table, THEN perform the `Func<T,bool>` (ie, an SQL type WHERE) on the data. This will become very inefficient, VERY fast.

```
 internal IDbSet<T> dbSet = _dbContext.Set<T>();

 public T Single(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
 {
     return dbSet.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
 }
```

In general, use IQueryable over IEnumerable in your repository. You want the major filtering of data at the database level, not in your code.

Answer (score 3):

All in all, not bad and pretty standard from what I can see.  A couple of small comments.

1. I would assume a `Get()` method would return a single item.  Hence to return a First would seem counter intuitive.  If I expect
   a method to return multiple I would call the `GetAll()`.  Consider renaming to `SingleOrDefault()`  Or altering it's implementation to using `SingleOrDefault()`.
2. Rather than using predicate as default I would consider creating an overload.  It gets rid of the little inline `iif` and makes it easier to read, in my opinion.

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
{
    return GetAll(() => true);
}

public IEnumerable<T> GetAll(Func<T, bool> condition)
{
    return _dbContext.Set<T>().Where(predicate);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This method and sig will pull down the entire database table each and every time

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetAll(Func<T, bool> predicate = null)
{
    IEnumerable<T> result = _dbContext.Set<T>().AsEnumerable();
    return (predicate == null) ? result : result.Where<T>(predicate);
}
```

Don't use `Queryable.AsEnumerable()` if you don't know what it does.

You need

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null)
{
    IQueryable<T> result = _dbContext.Set<T>();
    var ret = (predicate == null) ? result : Queryable.Where(result, predicate);
    return ret.AsEnumerable();
}
```

Your delete also suffers from the same problem.

Comment: Most important answer here.

Answer (score 2):

I'd change:

```
public void Delete(Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    IEnumerable<T> entities = GetAll(predicate);
    foreach (T entity in entities)
        _dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted;
}
```

to:

```
public void Delete(Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    IEnumerable<T> entities = GetAll(predicate);
    foreach (T entity in entities)
        Delete(entity);
}
```

This way, you reuse your `Delete(T Entity)` function so you only need to change `Delete(T Entity)` if your method of deletion should ever change.