# BaseRepository for EF6 - updated

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Previous question: [BaseRepository for EF6](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/51095)

I've update my code.  Is it correct now?  I've changed `IEnumerable` to `IQueryable`.

```
public interface IRepository<T> : IDisposable
{
    T Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    IQueryable<T> GetWhere(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null);
    void Add(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    void DeleteWhere(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    void Update(T entity);
    void Save();
}

public class BaseRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly DbContext _dbContext;

    public BaseRepository(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public T Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return GetWhere(predicate).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public IQueryable<T> GetWhere(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null)
    {
        IQueryable<T> result = _dbContext.Set<T>();
        return (predicate == null) ? result : Queryable.Where<T>(result, predicate);
    }

    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        _dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;
    }

    public void Delete(T entity)
    {
        _dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted;
    }

    public void DeleteWhere(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        IQueryable<T> entities = GetWhere(predicate);
        foreach (T entity in entities)
            Delete(entity);
    }

    public void Update(T entity)
    {
        _dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    public async void SaveAsync()
    {
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_dbContext != null)
            _dbContext.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> **DISCLAIMER** I don't believe in wrapping EF with a repository. Entity Framework *is* a unit-of-work and repository implementation.

> *I've changed IEnumerable to IQueryable.*

You've just destroyed the usefulness of your repository, and leaked Linq-to-Entities to your clients: it doesn't matter what `predicate` you give `GetWhere`, the client code can now just say `GetWhere().Where(x => whatever);`, and *the client code* now controls *when* (execution is deferred until the result is iterated) and *how* the query will run on the database server... **and that defeats the purpose of a repository**.

What you had before was much more robust.

One of the answerers of your other question said *In general, use IQueryable over IEnumerable in your repository.* - that did **not** mean to **expose** `IQueryable`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. As I understand, I don't need to cderate repository over EF. I can just use it by creating dataContext in Controllers (I usee it for MVC project)?

P.S. - sorry for my Engish)

Comment: I like making a small `IUnitOfWork` abstraction so I can inject a `DbContext` as a controller's dependency, and keep my code testable (without hitting db), but yeah, no repository for me ;)

Comment: I like it! Can you can give me link to github? I want to see some code.

Comment: @Roman [this answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/47904/23788) shows what I mean :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you give me link for understanding how to unit-testing it?

Comment: @Roman you know about [Dependency Injection](http://www.manning.com/seemann/)? I only test the business logic, I trust that EF works as it should - so instead of *depending* directly on a `DbContext` I *depend* on an `IUnitOfWork` that's implemented by a `DbContext` - unit tests inject a stub `IUnitOfWork` that isn't a `DbContext`. That simple ;)

Comment: It's something new for me. I didn't know about it. Thank you, mentor) I have a little question about IUnitOfWork interface. How to add SqlQueries Support, but with testability-saving? I need it to support calling stored-procedures. I working with an-existing databse, all business-logic is in stored procedures, and I need to call some of them from my code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14636/discussion-between-mats-mug-and-roman).